# pandas timeseries with relative time

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am new to pandas and I am struggling to figure out how to convert my data to a timeseries object. I have sensor data, in which there is a relative time index with reference to the beginning of the experiment. This is not in date/time format. All documentation that I have found online deals/starts with some sort of dated data. A short chunk of my data looks like:

```
0.000000    49.431958   4.119330    -0.001366   -9.483122E-9
0.025000    49.501745   4.125145    0.004710    2.322330E-8
0.050000    49.479531   4.123294    0.013725    1.185336E-7
0.075000    49.492309   4.124359    0.006082    1.607667E-7
0.325000    49.515702   4.126309    0.024307    9.750522E-7
2.925000    49.437069   4.119756    0.000202    9.148022E-6
3.025000    49.521010   4.126751    0.014313    9.590506E-6
3.425000    49.510001   4.125833    -0.003913   1.075210E-5
```

The time data is in the first column. I tried to load the data with:

```
datalabels= ['time', 'voltage pack', 'av. cell voltage', 'current', 'charge count', 'soc', 'energy', 'unknown1', 'unknown2', 'unknown3']
datalvm= pd.read_csv(dpath+dfile, header=None, skiprows=25, names=datalabels, delimiter='\t', parse_dates={'Timestamp':['time']}, index_col='Timestamp')
```

But I just get an indexed series, not a timeseries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: what do you want to do with this once you have it read in?

Comment: I want to be able to re-sample it as part of pre-processing for forecasting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should construct pandas TimeSeries objects by parsing the timestamps to dateTime objects.  This requires you to pick some arbitrary starting point

```
start = dt.datetime(year=2000,month=1,day=1)
time = datalvm['time'][1:]
floatseconds = map(float,time) #str->float

#floats to datetime objects -> this is you timeseries index
datetimes = map(lambda x:dt.timedelta(seconds=x)+start,floatseconds)

#construct the time series
timeseries = dict() #timeseries are collected in a dictionary
for signal in datalabels[1:]:
    data =map(float,datalvm[signal][1:].values)
    t_s = pd.Series(data,index=datetimes,name=signal)
    timeseries[signal] = t_s

#convert timeseries dict to dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(timeseries)
```

After you've constructed the timeSeries you can use the resample function:

```
dataframe['soc'].resample('1sec')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it using `cut` on the groupby (you can specify the bins if you want), or groupby however you want, using the data above (that's why I am reading via `StringIO`)

```
In [22]: df= pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None, delimiter='\s+')

In [23]: df.columns = ['time','col1','col2','col3','col4']

In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
    time       col1      col2      col3          col4
0  0.000  49.431958  4.119330 -0.001366 -9.483122e-09
1  0.025  49.501745  4.125145  0.004710  2.322330e-08
2  0.050  49.479531  4.123294  0.013725  1.185336e-07
3  0.075  49.492309  4.124359  0.006082  1.607667e-07
4  0.325  49.515702  4.126309  0.024307  9.750522e-07
5  2.925  49.437069  4.119756  0.000202  9.148022e-06
6  3.025  49.521010  4.126751  0.014313  9.590506e-06
7  3.425  49.510001  4.125833 -0.003913  1.075210e-05

In [25]: df.groupby(pd.cut(df['time'],2)).sum()
Out[25]: 
                    time        col1       col2      col3      col4
time                                                               
(-0.00343, 1.712]  0.475  247.421245  20.618437  0.047458  0.000001
(1.712, 3.425]     9.375  148.468080  12.372340  0.010602  0.000029
```

Comment: what is the -0.00343 (ah I see, a consequence of not using right=False), pd.cut very neat

Comment: yeh....``cut`` is pretty interesting here, can specify your own bins (which is prob what the op wants to do); easier than actually specifyng the groupby mapping, though could do that too

Comment: Thank you Jeff! This is obviously re-sampling my data, but I am not sure whether they are actually timeseries objects. I need to interface it with code that expects pandas timeseries.

Comment: They are not timeseries. Timeseries have an associated date (it could be the same ones). Why exactly do you need a timeseries?

Answer (score 1):

Beau's approach works nice, but I would like to avoid using the arbitrary starting point. I usually use TimedeltaIndex to make a time series so that I can only think about the time difference from t0.

```
time = datalvm['time'][1:]
floatseconds = map(float,time) #str->float
datalvm.index=pd.to_timedelta(floatseconds,unit='s')
```